# Why do some minified js files contain calls to "require" function

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, webpack-5

I've been modernizing some old gulp config where js files are concatenated and then minified by migrating to webpack.

Some of bundles contained libraries such as moment.js and isotope-docs.min.js,
When bundling with webpack I would get error that specific file or path is not found.

For example looking at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js)
There is `require("./locale/"+t)` which causes my webpack to fail since i dont have locale directory.

Why would bundled js file have `require` function when browsers dont understand that?

Comment: It's already been wrapped for use on the web, but webpack doesn't understand that and so is trying to re-wrap it when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thats what im suspecting, but it still doesn't make sense why would require function be called in the web bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Before [ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) became a thing, JavaScript did not have an official module syntax. Also, developers wanted to write a library once for both Node.js and the browser. The closest thing available was [Node.js's `require()`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/), which does not exist on the browser.

So what tools like [Browserify](https://browserify.org/) and [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) would do is *polyfill an implementation of `require()`* (e.g. wrap the code in a "[UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)"). This way, the module worked on any plaform and `require()` calls work as if in Node.js (its implementation may vary and can be extended because dealing with the filesystem is very different from dealing with a network).

Comment: I'm aware of that, why would there be require for browser builds? Is it in case it is ran outside browser?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, you can just add to webpack confing under module `noParse` e.g

*webpack.config.js*

```
module: { 
 rules: [ ... ]
 noParse: /moment.min.js|isotope-docs.min.js/
}
```